# What-is-the-difference-between-\psaxes in the following cases?

Tags: pstricks, pst-plot

```
\documentclass[border=15pt,pstricks]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-plot,pst-calculate}
\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}[showgrid,algebraic](-5,-1)(5,5)
\def\hamso{-1*x^2+4}
\def\hs{sqrt(-1*x^2+4)}
\def\k{\pscalculate{sqrt(3)}}
\psplot{-2}{2}{\hamso}
\pscustom[fillstyle=hlines]{%
\psplot{-\k}{\k}{\hs}
\psplot{\k}{-\k}{\hamso}}%
\pscustom[fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=red!50]{%
\psline(0,0)(+\k,\hs)
\psplot{\k}{-\k}{\hs}
\psline(+-\k,\hs)(0,0)
 }
%%%\psaxes{->}(0,0)(-3,-1)(3,5)[$x$,-90][$y$,0]
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

Without \psaxes...

[image]

With \psaxes...

[image]

Can anyone explain for me about this?

Another question: 
How to plot of function without "\pscalculate"?

Done!

```
\documentclass[border=15pt,pstricks]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-plot}
\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}[showgrid,algebraic](-5,-1)(5,5)
\def\hamso{-1*x^2+4}
\def\hs{sqrt(-1*x^2+4)}
\psplot{-2}{2}{\hamso}
\pscustom[fillstyle=hlines]{%
\psplot{3 sqrt}{3 sqrt neg}{\hs}
\psplot{3 sqrt neg}{3 sqrt}{\hamso}}%
\pscustom[fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=red!50]{%
\psline(0,0)(*{3 sqrt} \hs)
\psplot{3 sqrt}{3 sqrt neg}{\hs}
\psline(*{3 sqrt neg} \hs)(0,0)}
\psaxes[showgrid=false,showorigin=false]{->}(0,0)(-3,-1)(3,5)[$x$,-90][$y$,0]
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `showgrid` is true, `\psaxes` uses `style=gridstyleA`

```
\documentclass[border=15pt,pstricks]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-plot}
\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}[showgrid,algebraic](-5,-1)(5,5)
    \def\hamso{-1*x^2+4}
    \def\hs{sqrt(-1*x^2+4)}
    \def\k{1.732}
    \psplot{-2}{2}{\hamso}
    \pscustom[fillstyle=hlines]{%
        \psplot{-\k}{\k}{\hs}
        \psplot{\k}{-\k}{\hamso}}%
    \pscustom[fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=red!50]{%
        \psline(0,0)(+\k,\hs)
        \psplot{\k}{-\k}{\hs}
        \psline(+-\k,\hs)(0,0)
    }
\psaxes[labels=none,showgrid=false]{->}(0,0)(-3,-1)(3,5)[$x$,-90][$y$,0]
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: **\psplot{\k}{-\k}{\hs}**. Why can't we use _\psplot{sqrt(3)}{-sqrt(3}{\hs} or \psplot{! 3 sqrt}{! 0 3 sqrt sub}{\hs} or \pstVerb{/ds 3 sqrt def} ... \psplot{! -ds}{! ds}{\hs} or etc..._?

Comment: `\psplot{3 sqrt}{3 sqrt neg}{\hs}`